# spring not reading service repository from maven dependency

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am using a two maven projects i.e one is web application and other is maven jar. Dependency of jar is added to web application but during access to jar in web application

here is the code for web app

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {
    @Autowired
        private ServiceIntf intf;

        @RequestMapping("/")
        public String displayMessage(Model model) {
            String message = intf.message();
            System.out.println("\n\n\n\n" + message + "\n\n\n");
            model.addAttribute("message", message != null ? message : "null Value");
            return "index";
        }
    }
```

and service repository, from other project

```
@Service
public class ServiceClass implements ServiceIntf {

    Logger logger = Logger.getGlobal();

    public String message() {
        return "hello";
    }

}
```

jsp file

```
<body>
    <h1>Configured Context</h1>
    ABC
    <h1>${message}</h1>
    DEF
</body>
```

pom file for web application

```
    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
<!-- project dependency-->
                <groupId>test-core</groupId>
                <artifactId>test-core</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
```

In result I am getting printed **Configured Context** and **ABC XYZ** but not message. Please take a look and help me. if needed any more information let me know.

Edit: this is the error log I am getting form eclipse error log

```
The POM for test-core:test-core:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
```

Edit 2: after reinstalling `.m2` I am getting following error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'indexController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.api.service.intf; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.api.service.ServiceIntf] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

web configuration files

```
public class DispatcherServletConfiguration extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { ServletConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.api")
public class ServletConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

Note: Please forgive me for my bad english

Comment: is the sys out printing message correctly..

Comment: no it is not printing anything

Comment: then check your logs.. you should get some errors

Comment: @Jobin I have added logs information

Comment: your maven jar project is having some problem.. Did you do a `mvn install` for `test-core` project?

Comment: @Jobin I just did and after deleting and recreating `.m2` I am getting other error which I updated in question, Please check

Comment: Are you using component-scanning to get spring to auto-create your object instances? If so, what base-packages have you configured for scanning and is `com.api.service` among them? Otherwise how do you create your spring managed bean instances?

Comment: post your xml configuration file  or Annotation configuration class...

Comment: I do have component scaning in web app for package `com.api` and not in other file

Comment: @VNT I have added my configuration files

Comment: add the `package` to all classes

Comment: this is the packaging strategy for entire application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause for BeanCreationException is that bean with name `intf` is not present, so make any one of the following change. Make sure that you have `<context:component-scan base-package="your.base.package" />` added in spring xml file.

**Fix1:**

Change

```
@Service
public class ServiceClass implements ServiceIntf {
```

to

```
@Service("intf")
public class ServiceClass implements ServiceIntf {
```

OR

**Fix2**

change

```
@Autowired
private ServiceIntf intf;
```

to

```
@Autowired
private ServiceIntf serviceIntf;
```

Comment: I have implemented 2 of above methods and now trying form 2nd (`@Service("intf")`)

Comment: and it worked. I again removed and re-installed `m2` package and it started working, I am not sure what has happened and thanks for your assist sir :)

Comment: Autowiring by type should work just fine. I don't see why it should be necessary to specify and/or use a name since there's only one such service definition. From the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers): ` @Autowired is fundamentally about type-driven injection with optional semantic qualifiers`